# to copy values to a new table and delete values from old table

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigg_msg 
ON messagein 

FOR insert,delete,update AS 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) 
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO new_message (Phone number,CusID,CusName,CusAddress) values ( SELECT ins.sender FROM inserted ins, SELECT cus.CusID FROM customer cus, SELECT cusname FROM customer cus, SELECT cus.cus_phone number FROM customer cus, SELECT cus.Address FROM customer cus) 
DELETE * FROM messagein 
END
```

this trigger is not working.please somebody show me the mistake....

when insert a row to messagein table it should copy the value of sender field and copy it to the new_message table.then other values like cusID,CusName,.. should be retrieve from the customer table. please some one help me.

#### Update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigg_msg 

ON messagein 

FOR insert

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
 
BEGIN
 
INSERT INTO new_message(Phone_number,CusID,CusName,CusAddress) values ( SELECT ins.sender FROM inserted ins, SELECT cus.CusID, cus.cusname, cus.cus_phone_number,  cus.Address FROM customer cus)

DELETE FROM messagein
```

@Devart and @TudorConstantin Thank you very much for help me. finally i came up with this trigger but still getting errors.

Comment: Read the manual about triggers - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html. The trigger can be one of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. The trigger cannot modify the same table as specified in ON clause.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one syntax error:

```
DELETE * FROM messagein
```

Should be:

```
DELETE FROM messagein
```

Also, the INSERT should be:

```
INSERT INTO new_message (Phone_number,CusID,CusName,CusAddress) values ( SELECT ins.sender FROM inserted ins, SELECT cus.CusID, cus.cusname, cus.cus_phone_number,  cus.Address FROM customer cus)
```